# firebaseAppDistribution gradle configuration overwrite problem

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, firebase-app-distribution

I want to use `firebaseAppDistribution` in my project and I want to customize it fo every build type.

I have three buildType debug, staging and release. Each buildtype has a different destination group inside `firebaseAppDistribution.`

When I run the command to distribute the app on AppDistribute I noticed that group are always missing (but the artificat is correctly uploaded)

I think that the problem is related to how gradle work. I found a post on medium (https://medium.com/@anthony_m_cannon/android-firebase-app-distribution-for-multiple-build-types-4b50ff751ef0) that has the same problem for CI. The author solved it by using an ENV variable and run `firebaseAppDistribution` outside the buildType scope.

How can I solve in my local environment? Can I discrimante inside `build.gradle.kts` which buildType is currently running?

Gradle Version 7.6

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `firebaseAppDistribution { ... }` with:

```kotlin
configure<AppDistributionExtension> {
  [...]
}
```

inside the `buildType { ... }` scope seemed to do the trick for me.